# Using a scalar valued find string function when searching multiple rows returned?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, function

Given SQL Server 2008, I have written a simple find in string function as follows:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FindInString]
(
    @FindText VARCHAR(255),
    @TextSource VARCHAR(512)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Result INT
    SET @Result = 0

    SELECT @Result = CHARINDEX(@FindText, @TextSource)

    RETURN @Result
END
```

The complexity of the find function may change in the future, which is why I wanted to encapsulate it in a function.

Now, when I only have one matching record in a table, this works:

```
SELECT @FindCount = dbo.FindInString('somestring', (SELECT TableSearch FROM Segments WHERE CID=22793))
```

However, when the select statement returns more than one, it makes sense as to why an error is thrown.

like to know is what I need to do to still have this work as a simple call, as above?

I only need to know if there is one match (I just need to know if @FindCount > 0), and I'm guessing some sort of a loop may be required, but would like to keep this as simple as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregate functions and one select:

```
select
    @FindCount = sum(dbo.FindInString('somestring', TableSearch))
from
    Segment
where
    CID = 22793
```

Just take care with this, as `FindInString` will fire *for each row*, which can significantly reduce query performance. In this case, it's the only way to solve your problem, but just beware of the troubles that could arise.

Comment: CID's won't match more than 10 or 20 records or so, so this will work.  Thanks!